# Discord bot wont include space in string

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried making a command where the bot would copy everything I say. But the bot excludes everything behind spaces.
When I use !say aaa bbb, the bot will only reply with aaa, instead of aaa bbb.

```
@bot.command(name = 'say', help = 'make the bot say whatever you want')
async def sayy(ctx, amount: str):
    if amount == ("!say"):
        deathThreat = random.choice(deathThreats)
        await ctx.send(deathThreat)
    else:
        said = amount
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        await ctx.send(said)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place a `*` argument before `amount` so your `amount` contains everything after `!say`:

```py
@bot.command(name = 'say', help = 'make the bot say whatever you want')
async def sayy(ctx, *, amount: str):
    if amount == ("!say"):
        deathThreat = random.choice(deathThreats)
        await ctx.send(deathThreat)
    else:
        said = amount
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        await ctx.send(said)
```